# Android Registration form wont submit (Volley and SQL)

Tags: java, php, android

I'm still new to android programming and currently learning how to connect to DB.
I'm following a online tutorial but I'm still facing problems.
The tutorial is about create a registration form and sending it to the database through volley.
I'm using .hostinger.ae as host and Android studio.
Everything seems fine until I click the register button it give me an error of (Couldn't register )
I couldn't locate the error and debugging shows no errors. so please I would appreciate any help to locate the problem.

I have two php files uploaded to the online host on the public folder

dbconnect php The file used to connect to data base

```
<?php
define('HOST','mysql.hostinger.ae');
define('USER','--');
define('PASS','--');
define('DB','u853541076_tuber');
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
```

and the volleyRegister php

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
$username = $_POST['username'];    
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
require_once('dbConnect.php');
$sql = "INSERT INTO volley (username,password,email) VALUES('$username','$email','$password')";
  if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
  echo "Successfully Registered";
  }else{
  echo "Could not register";
  }
  }else{
 echo 'error';
 }
```

My mainactivty .java http://tuber.16mb.com is my domain

```
package myapp.com.tuberapp;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements     View.OnClickListener {
///The hosting link
public static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://tuber.16mb.com/volleyRegister.php";
public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private EditText editTextUsername;
private EditText editTextEmail;
private EditText editTextPassword;
private Button buttonRegister;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    editTextEmail= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
    buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
  }
  private void registerUser(){
    final String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
            params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
            params.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
   }
   @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == buttonRegister){
        registerUser();
    }
  }
  }
```

manifest.java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="myapp.com.tuberapp">


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: Try to register using Postman with your URL, Because i think there is problem with URL.

Comment: which URL you mean ?

Comment: REGISTER_URL = "http://tuber.16mb.com/volleyRegister.php"

Comment: Because on registration it showing Status: 200 ok but showing `access doneCould not register` this message

Comment: access done is message is just an echo I added to dbconnect to test the connection to locate the problem.  sorry about that. I've deleted by mistake from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit the URL on the browser directly.
http://tuber.16mb.com/volleyRegister.php

This will give error. Possibilities of error may be:
1. Your SQL insert statement is wrongly formed. Some table name or any other issues.
2. Your db configuration file may be some

Comment: THANK YOU ! your right ! I got the table name wrong stupid me.

Answer (score 0):

your query is not match "`INSERT INTO volley (username,password,email) VALUES('$username','$email','$password')"` . should its query is "`INSERT INTO volley (username,password,email) VALUES('$username','$password','$email')"

check again your server side code, check if the query already successful to insert data into your table.

Comment: I've edited the query but still the problem, And no data has been inserted into the tables